# Application of Stone Weierstrass Theorem for trigonometric polynomials

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, polynomials

In the space $C[-\pi, \pi]$ equipped with the sup norm, consider the linear space $M$ spanned by the functions ${ (\cos  nx)}_{n\geq0}$ and $ {(\sin nx)}_{n\geq1}$. what is the closure $\bar{M}$ of $M$ ?
What is the closure when it is equipped with the $L^2$ norm?

I know that$C_{\operatorname{per}}[-\pi, \pi]$ is a dense subset of $C[-\pi, \pi]$, but how do I move forward from here?

Comment: I'm assuming $C_{per}$ is the continuous periodic functions.

Comment: functions in  $C[-\pi, \pi]$ s.t. $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$.

Comment: @anaene You don't really need to consider $C_{per}$. By Stone-Weierstrass, $M$ is dense in $C$ for the sup norm. And by Parseval, it is dense in $L^2$ for the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: And actually, as you define it $C_{per}$ is closed fot the sup norm. So it is not dense in $C$.